# Class inheritance, overriding methods and accessing stored properties from superclass

Tags: ios, swift, oop

I'm learning Swift and object-orientated programming, and I've been stuck on a "quiz" for the past week. My task is to create a subclass of Machine called Robot, then override the move method from the superclass so that when I enter a particular string, the robot moves (up - y++, down - y--, right - x++, left - y--)

```
class Point {
    var x: Int
    var y: Int

    init(x: Int, y: Int){
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    }
}

class Machine {
    var location: Point

    init() {
        self.location = Point(x: 0, y: 0)
    }

    func move(direction: String) {
        print("Do nothing! I'm a machine!")
    }
}
```

What I'm really struggling with it how to OVERRIDE the move method. This is my thought process - please correct me where I'm wrong:

```
//The Robot class inherited the location stored property from its superclass; this property includes x and y as its of type Point
//x and y are already initialized in Robot because they're initialized in its super class
//I need to OVERRIDE the move method, so I cannot add x and y to the method's parameters or add a return type
//Therefore, I need to affect x and y without passing them into the method as arguments... and this is where I'm lost
```

This is the general idea of what I think needs to happen:

```
class Robot: Machine {
    let isRobot: Bool = true

    override func move(direction: String) {
        switch direction {
            case "Up":
            y++
            case "Down":
            y--
            case "Right":
            x++
            case "Left":
            x--
        default:
            break
        }
    }
}
```

If it's even possible to affect x and y in the method without passing them in as arguments, I've tried self.location = Point(x: x+1, y) and self.location += Point.x without success. These are new concepts for me and any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you checked this ? https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Inheritance.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're very, very close. Your only mistake is that `x` and `y` are not properties of `Machine`. They're properties of `Machine.location`.

Your `self.location = Point(x: x+1, y)` should work, so I'm curious what "without success" means there. The simpler way is exactly as you've done, but modifying the location:

```
     case "Up":
         location.y++
```

Likely unrelated, but your `Point` would be significantly better implemented as a `struct` rather than a `class`. Using a `Point` as a mutable reference type (a class that includes `var` properties) can lead to a lot of confusion. If two `Robot` instances are passed the same `Point`, then modifications to one will also modify the other, which would be very surprising. A `struct`, on the other hand, is a value type. If you pass it to something, the receiver gets its own copy.

Reference types (classes) are best used when the thing has an identity and its own state. Two robots at the same location are still different robots. But two points at the same location are the same point. That means points are values and should be a `struct`.

Comment: Thanks for your help Rob, using location.x/y worked! I believe the issue with `self.location = Point(x: x+1, y)` is related to the resource that is checking my answer as the code complies just fine for me. And I agree about Point being better as a struct, I'm just going through the exercise with what they give me :)